# Magento admin page shoes title but no navigation or anything below

Tags: magento, admin

I am able to log into admin but once opened it only shows the top header MAGENTO ADMIN PANEL everything below is blank
I have cleared cache folder.

Help please!

Comment: Magento Version 1.8.1

Comment: I cannot post a screenshot at the moment as my score is not high enough. Let me know what information you need to offer me assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting some error in your script. Check the system and exception log for more information if they are enabled.

Also, use the following lines in your index.php file so that error can be made visible:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: It is not showing anything in the log. Is it maybe not showing an error as it thinks it has logged in ok?

Comment: Just to point out that this site has been up for around 12 months now without any issues. No modules have been installed recently either.

Comment: Logs may be disabled in your website. It can be enabed from admin via System >> Configuration >> Developer >> Log Settings

Comment: If it is up from last 12 months then may be there could be space issue at server or expiry of some module function etc. Real situation can't be guess from here

Comment: I cannot navigate in admin so cannot go System >> Configuration >> Developer >> Log Settings

Comment: Run this query in database: select * from  core_config_data  where path='dev/log/active' and then update the 'value' field to 1 for this

Comment: What about adding those 2 lines in index.php...Is ur frontend working properly? Its hard to tell with this limited info about the issue

Comment: Front end works fine. Added the two lines into the index.php can I PM you with more details?